# how start timer by pressing a button in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I need to make sure that after pressing the button, the timer turns on

i have a timer

```
class Timer extends React.Component {

  
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {minute:0, second:0}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      setInterval (() => {
          return this.setState((state) => {

              return{
                  second: state.second==59?0:state.second+1,
                  minute: state.second==59?state.minute+1:state.minute
              }
          });
      }, 1000);

      
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <p>{this.state.minute}:{this.state.second}</p>
      );
  }
  
  
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Timer />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('timer')
);
```

and example button

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('rollButton')
);
```

how can i make it start rendering the timer after the button is pressed?
I will be glad if you make a timer stop function too)

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

To make the timer work you first need to add the **Toggle** component as a child component for the **Timer**, as you need to pass the state between the two components. I've also created a function to update the time of your state.

```
class Timer extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { minute: 0, second: 0 };
        this.updateTimer = this.updateTimer.bind(this);
      }
    
      updateTimer() {
        this.setState((state) => {
          return {
            second: state.second === 59 ? 0 : state.second + 1,
            minute: state.second === 59 ? state.minute + 1 : state.minute
          };
        });
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <>
            <p>
              {this.state.minute}:{this.state.second}
            </p>

            <Toggle updateTimer={this.updateTimer} />
          </>
        );
      }
    }
```

Then on the **Toggle** component you need to add the lifecycle method *componentDidUpdate*. What this method does is to check if a prop or state has changed/updated. So in this method we're going to check if the toggle button was clicked, and then, if is it on, we run the setInterval callback, otherwise, we clear the interval so the timer pauses. Also I've added a global value in order to store the interval (you can use Refs also here). If you need to reset the timer, pass another method as prop to the Toggle to clean the state on stop.

```
import { Component } from "react";

class Toggle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: false };
    this.interval = null;
    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.isToggleOn !== this.state.isToggleOn) {
      if (this.state.isToggleOn) {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.props.updateTimer, 1000);
      } else {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? "OFF" : "ON"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Toggle;
```

Comment: @juanrieyes if i need to render the button separately from the timer do i need to edit the css? also I didn't quite understand how to stop the timer and delete the contents

Comment: What do you mean by separately, like not importing the Toggle on the Timer? And the method “clearInterval(this.interval)” is the one that stops the timer, is removing the previously created interval, that’s why it stops. And to delete the contents, you have to pass another prop to the Toggle component, like I did passing the “updateTimer”, there you set the state to its default values, e.g, this.setState({ minute: 0, second: 0 });

Comment: @juarineyes i mean i already have buttons on their needed positon can i render to this position?

Comment: @juarineyes TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

this.setState(() => ({
    state: {minute: 0, second: 0}
}));

Comment: Hmm, if you have created another method for clearing the state, did you defined the .bind(this) call? I've created a sandbox with the "delete the contents" functionality so you can check it. https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-kalam-8kc3b
Good luck!